# java runtime NullPointerException despite initialising

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a null pointer exception despite initialising all of my objects correctly (to my knowledge). Baiscially, I need someone to point out where I've been an idiot.

The runtime NPE occurs here:

```
public class CDAlbum implements Album{
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private String artist;
    private ArrayList<String> tracks;
    private int i=0;

    public CDAlbum() {    //constuctor
        title   = "Unknown CD";
        genre   = "Unknown genre";
        artist = "Unknown artist";
        ArrayList<String> tracks = new ArrayList<String>(); //NPE occurs on this line
        tracks.add("-- no tracks --");
    }
    //snip
```

And the code calling the constructor:

```
CDAlbum tempCD;
tempCD = new CDAlbum();
```

I think I'm initialising everything properly, so I can't see where this null pointer exception is coming from. A little help?

Comment: Your code here is probably modified and not the actual code producing the exception; you're more than likely trying to `add` to the `tracks` field, however you never initialized it (you only initialized the local variable `tracks`).

Comment: Try `tracks = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton("-- no tracks --"));` PS you can move all of your initialization to the field declarations, e.g. `private String title = "Unknown CD";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, your problem was because you had forgotten to recompile your code! After downloading the code from your dropbox, I decompiled `CDAlbum` to reveal an outdated constructor:

```
public CDAlbum() {
  i = 0;
  title = "Unknown CD";
  genre = "Unknown genre";
  artist = "Unknown artist";
  tracks.add("-- no tracks --");
}
```

After recompiling (after following my suggestions), the code appeared to work fine.

---

As I stated in [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126668/java-runtime-nullpointerexception-despite-initialising#comment16216772_12126668), your code here is probably modified and **not** the actual code producing the exception; you're more than likely trying to add to the `tracks` field, however **you never initialized it**  -- you *only* initialized the local variable `tracks`.

Try doing something like the following...

```
tracks = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton("-- no tracks --"));
```

You should post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) or at least the unmodified code to receive accurate help. It's going to be tough to solve the issue if you treat it as a black box.

---

Note you can move all of your initialization to the field declarations, e.g.

```
private String title = "Unknown CD";
```

Comment: runtime error: http://puu.sh/YPUq

the CDAlbum.java:15 is the indicated constructor line and the CollectionFactory.java:69 is the second line in the second code snippet.

both code snippets are straight copypasted from my source files.

if you want more code I can post more, just tell me which snippet needs elaboration.

Comment: @thorium220 can you paste all of `CDAlbum.java`? Use http://pastie.org if formatting for SO is too much of a hassle.

Comment: Now, can you show me `CollectionFactory.java`? I have an idea.

Comment: 'i have an idea' has never sounded so... ominous.
here: http://pastie.org/4588810
the offending method starts at 64.

Comment: @thorium220 hm, can you create an SSCCE like I asked earlier? Being able to actively debug should let me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure i'd be able to do that quickly. will a dropbox link for the entire project do? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zz8vdzqgw296s3d/v_cfW5svHG

Comment: no I was recompiling every time, and saving my changes in np++ each time too, but i just recompiled and ran and got this: http://puu.sh/YQR4 . I dunno about you, but I'm blaming gremlins. thanks for all the help, mate, i really appreciate anyone who will put up with a student stupid enough to leave programming assignments till 2 days before they're due (this one's due in 12.5hrs).

Comment: @thorium220 I had to compile the packaged code separately, i.e. `javac au/edu/uow/Collection/CDAlbum.java` :-)

Comment: really? I had been taught that the compiler will recompile any and all modified files used by the (for want of a better term) 'main' file (in this case, the MyCollectionjava file). At any rate, thanks again for all the help and sorry for my incompetence.

Comment: @thorium220 not from what I can tell :-/

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
ArrayList<String> tracks = new ArrayList<String>();
```

should be

```
tracks = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You are re-declaring it when you shouldn't be since you've already declared it at class scope above

```
private ArrayList<String> tracks;
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the exception at hand.

Comment: I did this, but the exception still occurs.